# How to sort filenames that are numbered with various conventions

Tags: bash

This is similar to my previous question, but I think it's more different than it is similar.

I have a folder in Bash. In that folder, are numbered files, all of the same filetype. Those files have filenames that cannot contain spaces. I need to sort those files by number. Say, if the folder contained:

```
1.jpg
1.2.jpg
ch.002.jpg
Chapter3.jpg
Chapter_004:_Blah.jpg
Chapter_4.1.jpg
Chapter_5.jpg
Chapter_5.005.jpg
```

The resulting string would be

```
"1.jpg 1.2.jpg 002.jpg Chapter3.jpg Chapter 004:_Blah.jpg Chapter_4.1.jpg Chapter_5.jpg Chapter_5.005.jpg"
```

As you can see, I need support for floats, numbers with leading zeros, and regular numbers.

Comment: Have you been check out `sort` command? You can pipe it `ls` command. Just read the man page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have stated **Those files have filenames that cannot contain spaces.** you can use a fairly simple Bash pipeline to generate a DSU (Decorate Sort Undecorate or Schwartzian transform) using `*` and `gawk` and a numerical sort. (If the files could contain spaces, the method is the same but we would need to use a Bash loop instead of the `tr ' ' '\n'` to delimit each file name.)

Given these files:

```
$ echo *
1.2.jpg 1.jpg Chapter3.jpg Chapter_004:_Blah.jpg Chapter_4.1.jpg Chapter_5.005.jpg Chapter_5.jpg ch.002.jpg
```

You can do:

```
$ echo * | tr ' ' '\n' | gawk '{match($0, /([0-9]+\.{0,1}[0-9]*)/, arr); print arr[1] "/" $0}' | sort -n | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}' | tr '\n' ' '
1.jpg 1.2.jpg ch.002.jpg Chapter3.jpg Chapter_004:_Blah.jpg Chapter_4.1.jpg Chapter_5.jpg Chapter_5.005.jpg
```

Whatever conditions you want to add to the decoration portion, you would add by changing the regex in `match($0, /([0-9]+\.{0,1}[0-9]*)/, arr)` to capture that portion from the file name.

In Unix, the character `/` is an illegal filename character and therefor an effective delimiter between the decoration and the filename. We then sort numerically on the float interpretation of the decoration and remove the decoration with a second `awk`.

If you wanted to add multiple conditions to `sort` you can add multiple decorations with the first `awk` with an illegal filename character as the delimiter. Then appropriately use the multi field arguments to `sort` and undecorate with the last `awk` command to print the filename.

Answer (score 3):

A [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) with paste, GNU sort and bash:

```
paste <(tr -cd '[0-9.\n]' < file | sort -V) file | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' '
```

Output:

```
1.jpg 1.2.jpg 002.jpg Chapter3.jpg Chapter_004:_Blah.jpg Chapter_4.1.jpg Chapter_5.jpg Chapter_5.005.jpg
```

Comment: I am a sucker for any DSU / Schwartzian transform method.